# Ruby, twilio: SocketError "getaddrinfo: No such host is known"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

When I try to send a text message on my rails app I get this error. Wasn't there up to a week a go. I tried pinging the host Twilio in prompt and I get a response.

Is this a DNS issue? And if so any fix? I have the correct credentials in my action:

```
def send_text_message
    number_to_send_to = params[:number_to_send_to]

    twilio_sid = "*sid*"
    twilio_token = "*token*"
    twilio_phone_number = "+14804188101"

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token

    @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => "+14804188101",
      :to => "*number*",
      :body => "test"
    )

   end
```

Bizarre

Thanks

Comment: Have you add `require 'twilio-ruby'` to a file where you have got this method?

Comment: Megan from Twilio here. Are you running production or local development only?

Comment: Hi Megan, it's actually working now. I did not change anything. If it happens again I'll mention it. I have no idea why it happened. It's local development. Thanks! Also @ Mateusz.